# SharePoint 2010 - Add WebPart reference to PowerShell script

Tags: web-part, powershell, assembly-references

I want to add a new developed WebPart to a SharePoint site with PowerShell.

How it is possible to add the WebPart reference from my WebPart to the PowerShell script?

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $urlWeb

$webpartmanager=$web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($urlWebWP,  [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

$webpart = new-object  ReferenceToMyWebPartProblem

$webpartmanager.AddWebPart($webpart, $webpartzone, $index);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [link](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/How%20to%20create%20Web%20Part%20instances%20on%20pages%20using%20PowerShell%20and%20SPLimitedWebPartManager.aspx) to a page that describes the process for the out of the box SharePoint webparts.  If you want to include your own webpart, you need to add a reference to your assembly in powershell.  The following line adds a reference to one of my custom webparts into powershell.

```
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("rossri.NavigationControl, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a60d1a662835ad70")
```

Once the reference is added, I can then create a new object of the type of my custom webpart.  For fun I changed the title and then added it using the webpartmanager object.

```
$webpart = New-Object rossri.NavigationControl.UserListViewPart.UserListViewPart
$webpart.Title = "NewPart from Powershell"
$webpartmanager.AddWebPart($webpart, "Left", "0")
```

I checked the page and it was added to the zone I defined.